# Markup in retail, are these examples kosher?

Tags: halacha, business

I have noticed that Keter Judaica, the American importer for Mishkan HaTchelet seems t have some pretty outrageous markups.

Example 1: Keter Traditional Touch Tallit (M"T Tzemer A.A.) (size 55)

- Keter: $140
- M"T: ₪299 (roughlt $80 at the time of this posting)

Example 2: tzitzit (cotton begged) (size 6=24)

- Keter: $13.50 ($18 at local fromm Judaica store)
- M"T: ₪19 (roughly $5)

While I haven't done out the math here, the price difference is pretty stark, which leads to my question: are these markups actually kosher?

Comment: Why would they be 'non-kosher'? Do the Shekel prices include shipping stateside?

Comment: @DoubleAA, no, but I can't see the shipping being up to twice the cost per item in the quantities that they'd need to import for business. They'd presumably also receive bulk discounts, as I've heard is standard in wholesale. I should actually probably be saying yashar (upright) following R' Breuer's philosophy of kosher v'yausher.

Comment: _Choshen Mishpat_ 231, toward the end.

Comment: You would need to check the increases due to the middlemen (if there are any) and the actual shipping costs. What would it coust to get ordered directly from Eretz Yisroel?

Comment: @sabbahillel, If I order from Ben's Tallit Shop, the Tzemer AA would cost $91 with shipping

Comment: I've also noticed that a lot of my competitors, especially US-based online vendors, have much higher prices than we do. Here are a few possible reasons to be lomed zechus: 1) Import taxes. 2) Need to keep a large stock. 3) Mishkan Hatchelet is the manufacturer, whereas Keter is a distributor. 4) Mishkan Hatchelet has just a rudimentary website; I doubt they provide much service in English. 5) Keter spends money on US marketing. In Israel, Mishkan Hatchelet relies largely on its reputation and the presence of its outlet stores. 6) Keter is in NY. Mishkan spends much less on rent in Be'er Sheva.