# Kippah vendor websites

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, kippa-yarmulka

This is a fairly simple question, however, my experience with Google makes it seem much more difficult. What is a good website for getting non-bulk kippot in personal styles (eg. velvet, suede, knit/crocheted, not these cheap, satiny types one might find at many heterodox schuls)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Eichler's collection of yarmulkles](https://www.eichlers.com/garments/kippot-yarmulkas.html). They seem to have what you're looking for. That page has links for lists of Kippot and Yarmulkes that are velvet, suede, knit, or "customized" (as well as for events), to be sold individually (ie not in bulk):

> Here, you can find kippot in knit, suede, satin, and velvet as well as
>   hand-painted children's styles, kippot for babies, and much more.
>   [...] Finally, for those who need their kippot in bulk, we have you
>   covered with our Kippot by the Dozen!

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.judaica.com/. I ordered a few items from there (not kippot), previously. I was quite pleased. I just browsed the kippot area, and they have a wide selection of styles and a wide price range. Pricing seems pretty reasonable to me. (Then again, lately, I'v been getting most of my kippot for free from a Bar Mitzvah or wedding, somewhere.)

Answer (score 1):

[Keter Judaica](http://keterjudaica.com/Yarmulkahs-Kipas/) has quite a nice selection of yarmulkes, available in many materials, both traditional and modern, and in bulk if needed.

Comment: I actually checked Keter. Their shipping costs more than their kippot

Comment: Same with Eichler's. Actually, [Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/24cm-Black-Velvet-Kippah-Section/dp/B00NPDUZWC/ref=pd_sim_193_2?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00NPDUZWC&pd_rd_r=MR0VQC1NNWZ0HH830G89&pd_rd_w=jS6AJ&pd_rd_wg=YKlRC&psc=1&refRID=MR0VQC1NNWZ0HH830G89) might be a good place.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt "Their shipping costs more than their kippot." It sounds like they have the costs of their kippot "covered", then :-) :-)

Comment: I don't know why, but for some reason most Judaica stores from New York have horrible shipping rates. One time, I ordered two pocket sized siddurim from Kehot, and the shipping costed as much as an express order for a tallis katan from Ben's Tallit Shop in Israel. Must be my area.

Comment: It feels like ona'ah to me. Keter in particular has some particularly egregious prices, both for shipping and their rebranded Mishkan haTchelet tallitot. I don't think it's just your area, as I live near Boston and the shipping for three kippot was slightly more than the $18 for three kippot.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Wow. I'm amazed. I think that is ona'ah. I didn't know  their tallitot were just Mishkan haTchelet ones with a fancy tag. Good to know.

Comment: The rebranding is perfectly aboveboard.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60144/markup-in-retail-are-these-examples-kosher